# Spring Security returns login page despite permitAll

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I know there is a lot of questions like this, but I could not find an answer which solves my case.

Here is my config:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout().permitAll();
    }
}
```

And here is my endpoint I want users to have access without logging in:

```java
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/", consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public void acceptAnonymously(HttpEntity<String> requestEntity) {
        log.debug("body: {}", requestEntity.getBody());
    }

}
```

So basically, I want to allow making unauthenticated POST requests to `localhost:8080`. Everything else should be authenticated. But when I hit `localhost:8080` with postman, this is what I get:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that has to do with Spring Security ? That sign-in page seems unrelated but, if it was it would probably be due to .formLogin(). Additionally, not sure if it makes a difference but, I always use '/**' to authenticate all requests for any URI

Comment: I guess using  `/**` will allow making POST requests to endpoints like `/test`, `/test/test/test`, so it's undesirable behavior for me.

Comment: @user3696953 Not 100% sure it's related to Spring Security, I'm just getting started. But it seems (to me) like Spring Security is completely ignoring my `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/").permitAll()` line and therefore returning login page due to `.anyRequest().authenticated()`.

Comment: @user3696953 If I disable the login page with `.formLogin().disable()`, `403 Forbidden` is returned in Postman.

Comment: Maybe try disabling these other items as well
`.formLogin().disable()`
`.httpBasic().disable()`
`.logout().disable()`
`.csrf.disable()`

Comment: @user3696953 Ok, I've figured out that `.csrf().disable()` is the solution. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, CSRF stands for Cross-Site Request Forgery and I believe is enabled by default with Spring Web/Security. When it is enabled, you need to properly pass the correct csrf token to your app in order to access your application otherwise you will get thrown a 403 forbidden type error. Alternatively, there are other means of authenticating users if you so desired.

`.csrf().disable()`

Answer (score 0):

Actually disabling CSRF is not a good idea for all situations. CSRF is enabled by default and as a result, the CSRF token is added to the HttpServletRequest attribute named `_csrf`. So you only need to add it to your requests.
If you are using Thymeleaf for your html templates you could add something like this to your forms:

```
<input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```